# Android Studio Cannot find Android Studio project files

Tags: android-studio, build

I was given a sample code from a factory and said that it was created using Android Studio. But whenever I try to build, it says that cannot find the project files, and asked me to perform a full rebuild.

I have tried numerous suggestions given on the net (mostly outdated), but can't figure out what was missing.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.io.IOException) Cannot find Android Studio project files at C:/Factory
java.io.IOException: Cannot find Android Studio project files at C:/Factory
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:42)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:50)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:281)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

Comment: It would help people answering to know what all you've tried but has not worked to avoid repeating the same tips. Kindly, add to the question, what all fixes you've tried.

Comment: I didn't even try to fix any thing. Just load it using Android Studio. And I can't figure out what might had gone wrong

Comment: You said; "...I have tried numerous suggestions given on the net ". Anyways, it seem's your project files might've gotten corrupted or something as the IDE cannot find the project; `Cannot find Android Studio project files at C:/Factory`
If you've got all the sourcecode and files, java classes, xml layouts and res folder contents and manifest files etc. You can Build a new project and move individual files one by one or copy into new files named similarly.

Comment: MD Naseem Ashraf, hat for the reply. It is possible if I am the only one who is using the sample, and I will not get any future updates from the factory. Otherwise it is a big hassle to do it again and again in future.